# How can i load data with react from firebase db

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hi my question is how can i load data from the firebase db when a user is clicking on a button.
i want the "data" paragraph to show only when the user click on the "More info" button and hide it when they click on it again.
here is the code of my Product component any advice will be very appreciated:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Css/Product.css'


function Product({name , price , image, data,}) {

  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product">
      <div className="product__info">
       <h3>{name}</h3>
       <button className="product__button">More info...</button>  
       <p>{data}</p>
       <p className="product__price">
       <small>₪</small>
       <strong>{price}</strong>
       </p>
      </div>
      <img src={image} atl="img"/>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```